# Clicking Pidgin message in Ubuntu 13.10 indicator menu doesn't focus on message

Tags: unity, 13.10, indicator, pidgin

When I get a message on Pidgin, if I click the notification in the indicator panel, it doesn't bring the message into focus. It highlights that the message has been opened in the Unity dock, but I have to click the dock icon or alt-tab to the window to read the message. Does anyone know a fix so I can view the messages from the indicator notification? (Note: this actually works in 12.04, so I'm assuming it's a bug in the later version).

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: It is a bug, and one I'm not sure how to fix. It worked when pidgin was first ported to the new messaging menu api in 12.10, and part of the 13.04 cycle, but broke sometime in 13.04. It just uses gtk_window_present, but unity decided to only wiggle the icon when that happens.

Comment: I've recently updated to 14.04 and the problem persists, but it turns out I can't replicate it on another machine running 14.04. I have also noticed that I get a similar problem with other programs - for instance, Rhythmbox doesn't come to foreground if it's clicked in the Sound Menu. I'm wondering if this is something to do with Nvidia drivers, as that's one obvious difference between the two 14.04 machines. Think I'll need to do some deeper digging!

Answer (score 0):

Try Guifications Plugin for Pidgin. Install it via terminal with `sudo apt-get install pidgin-guifications`, provide your user password and allow the plugin to be installed after which you can go to the Tools menu and choose Plugins, in the list of the installed Plugins you'll find "Guifications" as shown in the next screenshot:

[image]

After activating the Plugin you'll be able to configure it and certain things like: what to do when clicking, right clicking, etc.

[image]

The defaul themes look somehow ugly, but you can get other themes from **[this site](http://sourceforge.net/p/guifications/themes/)** in order to improve your experience when using Guifications.

Oh! Yes... I almost forget to tell: You may wish to disable the Libnotify Popups plugin in order to not to receive double notifications.

Good luck!

Comment: The correct package name is pidgin-guifications, so to install use sudo apt-get install pidgin-guifications